# Data aggregation in Teradata / Tableau

Tags: sql, teradata, tableau-api

I need to add the below flag to a tableau dashboard:

**case when planned_action=1 and actual_action=0 then 1 
else 0
end as protection_flag**

for which I need data at aggregated level using the above flag.

I need to calculate action_rate:

**sum(action)/sum(total_occurrences)**

When I use group by in SQL Teradata using the protection_flag, and then calculate action_rate, as similar rows are getting grouped, 
for **protection_flag=1**, the action_rate,

**(sum(planned_action)/sum(total_occurrences))** is always 100%.

How do I rectify this? Or Is there any way I can add this filter directly on tableau. I am new to SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are summing `planned_action`, but the first sentence is about `protection_flag`.  Hence, I am confused.

Comment: can you give us the table structures and a data sample on which you are trying to build your query. @Akshaya Janardhanan